# Rxjs/reactor limit operator equivalent for ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs, reactor

What i am trying to achive is execute many ajax requests(vary from 10 to 1000+) concurrently but on a limit of active requests of 5 (like a FIFO queue in terms of execution of the request).

For example we have an array of 100 http address and we want to get first 5 and perform a GET request for each one, if any of these five requests ends then another address should enter the queue and perform its GET request untill all 100 addresses make a request and finish.

With the reactor library there is [limitRequest](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#limitRequest-long-) operator which fits my description

my question is how do i achive a similar behaviour with rxjs?

I tried with buffer operator but it emits results every 5 requests completed, what i want is to emit results as soon as a request is completed.

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/photo-dls-2krgxm?file=index.js)

trying to experiment on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all this with just two `mergeMap`s. The `mergeMap` operator accepts a second parameter which is the number of concurrent Observables. The first `mergeMap` will be used to unpack the array of URLs coming from the server and the second one will keep 5 concurrent requests:

Based on your stackblitz demo (thanks for providing a demo by the way) you can put all this into a single RxJS chain.

```
from(axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")).pipe(
  mergeMap(response => response.data // Unwrap the array of URLs into single emissions
    .filter(x => x.albumId === 100)
    .map(x => x.url)
  ),
  mergeMap(url => of(url).pipe(delay(1000 * Math.random())), 5), // Mock additional requests with of() and delay()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/photo-dls-pb27pn?file=index.js

Comment: wow thanks that is great i also used mergeMap finally but this solution is much more cohesive